# How do you bind Tomcat to a specific interface when running it through Maven?

Tags: maven, tomcat

By default Tomcat only listens on localhost when run using "mvn tomcat:run". How can I bind to a specific, or all, interfaces instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`serverXml`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#serverXml) option.